# after server upgrade, if I enable custom permalinks, my /feed stops working

Tags: feed

I have recently moved server and upgraded my wordpress install to the latest version.

Now if I try to access /feed, I get a 404. It used to work. /?feed=atom works correctly.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I fixed it. Virtual host definition had AllowOverrides turned off, so .htaccess was not being picked up. Thanks all for the comments.

Comment: Do your other pretty permalinks work?

Comment: Is your .htaccess writable?

Comment: Please put your solution in answer to the question. It is ok to answer your own question because it is more clear for those who might encounter this issue and question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress writes url rewriting rules to the .htaccess file, but apache will only use the .htaccess file if AllowOverrides is allowed for the directory where the .htaccess is located.

I enabled it by setting `AllowOverride All` in the virtualhost configuration, and my permalinks are now working again.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Delete your existing .htaccess, and re-enable the permalinks.
2. Like Kaaviar said, check if .htaccess is writeable, else, you may have to create it on your own.

Traps:

1. Does your new server have .htaccess and mod_rewrite enabled?